# Laravel: Unable to echo $message variable after Reirection with $message

Tags: php, variables, redirect, laravel, undefined

I am redirecting using the following code

```
return Redirect::to("update/a/product")
->with("message", "Product Successfully Updated");
```

But when I try to echo `$message` variable inside my view, I get an error of undefined variable.

Answer (score 5):

How are you defining/echoing `$message`? Since you are [returning a redirect with flash data](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects), access it using [Session::get()](http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-usage), which you can also check it is there first with [Session::has()](http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-usage)

```
<?php
if (Session::has('message')) {
    $message = Session::get('message');
    echo $message;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you passed is flash data.  You'll have to process the flash data when it gets to the "update/a/product" route.

You could use `Session::get('message')`